# MySQL Table COLLATION utf8_turkish_ci To utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation, utf8mb4

I have 2 table and I want to do join those tables. But one table collation is *utf8_turkish_ci* another is *utf8_general_ci*. These tables are big (2.9GB / 550MB) So I don't want to use "**COLLATION**" keyword in query because it's decelerated to my query.

My question is: if I change the table COLLATION from utf8_turkish_ci To utf8_general_ci so garble or change any character in rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collation changing do not change characters. The collation is a rule (or rules) which say how to compare characters.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-general.html) - *A character set is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set.*